# CoreData returning NSManagedObjects instead of subclass in Unit Tests

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a "Data" class that subclasses "NSManagedObject" with a single bool property "attribute".  I've also defined a method "whoisyou" on the class "Data".  This code runs in the app, but as soon as I put this code in my UnitTest, Core Data returns a "NSManagedObject" instead of a "Data" object and the "attribute" property works, but the "whoisyou" method throws an "unrecognized selector" exception.

```
Data *data = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Data" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];

NSLog(@"TYPE: %@", [data class]);

data.attribute = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
STAssertTrue([data.attribute boolValue], @"should have been TRUE");
data.attribute = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
STAssertFalse([data.attribute boolValue], @"should have been FALSE");

[data whoisyou];
```

What's the deal with the Unit Test environment?

Comment: Are your custom classes .m files included in the tests target?

Comment: well there ya go :-) - post an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your custom classes implementation files are included in the unit tests target. :)